# How to place image inline in Flex 4.6

Tags: image, apache-flex, inline

I have a list of s checkboxes, and I would like to have a tiny image after each line of lebal text. Unfortunately default Flex fonts look a bit different on different OS and browser combinations, so I cannot place it there manually, but I need to attach it programmatically.
Here is how my checkboxes look like. I use Flex 4.6, how is it possible to do so ?

```
<s:CheckBox x="10" y="60" label="label1" id="1CB" click="modify();"/>
<s:CheckBox x="10" y="75" label="label2" id="2CB" click="modify();"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very well try this, the resolution will not change for differnent OS once the width and height of the images are set. Similarly an Image can be added through actionscript also.

```
<s:HGroup>
    <s:CheckBox x="10" y="60" label="label1" id="CB"/>
    <mx:Image source="@Embed('untitled.png')" width="50" height="50"/>  
</s:HGroup>

<s:HGroup>
    <s:CheckBox x="10" y="75" label="label2" id="CB2"/>
    <mx:Image source="@Embed('untitled.png')" width="50" height="50"/>
</s:HGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use embed fonts for this, they will be show equal in all OS. For examle, write in style file:

```
@font-face
{
    fontFamily: HelveticaNeueLTStd;
    src: url("assets/font/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt.otf");
    embedAsCFF: true;
    advancedAntiAliasing: true;
}

global
{
    font-family: HelveticaNeueLTStd;
    fontSize: 16;
}
```